# subsonic with oracle database

Tags: asp.net, oracle, orm, subsonic

Can anyone advise on the best Oracle ASP.NET 3.5 ORM in the land..pros and cons?

How good is Subsonic 3.0 with Oracle?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you specified which version(s) of the .NET Framework you are using.  It would also help if you specified which version of SubSonic you are interested in as 2.2 is significantly different from 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main choice is between NHibernate and Entity Framework.  NHibernate generally wins those comparisons.

I don't believe SubSonic 3 supports Oracle.

You can read more about .NET ORMs here:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)

Comment: There are also many commercial .NET ORMs out there, but they don't seem to offer too much differentiation from NHibernate and Entity Framework.  Some of them monitor Stack Overflow and may post answers here.